# What are this java while loops doing in merge sort?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, divide-and-conquer

Step one and step two (step three) seem like repeatedly running to me. Why is it programmed like this?

```
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    int k = l; 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {     ----step one
        if (L[i] <= R[j]){ 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else{ 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 
    while (i < n1){             ---step two
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 
    while (j < n2){         ----step three
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This code is just doing the merge step, merging arrays L and R into arr. Step 2 and 3 are adding the remaining numbers, only one of the 2 will ever be executed, this is after the end of L or R was reached, to fill in the remaining values of the other array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Step one" does the work of merging from two source arrays into the destination. When `L` or `R` is exhausted there may still be unmerged elements remaining in the other source array. "Step two" exists to copy any remaining elements from `L` to the destination. "Step three" serves the same purpose for `R`.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to skip those steps and just use a for loop, if that is easier for you in the following way:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if(r >= right.size() || (l < left.size() && left[l] < right[r])) {
                arr[i] = left[l++];
            } else {
                arr[i] = right[r++];
            }
        }
arr.size() = n1 + n2 in your implementation
```

or even this:

```
while(len--) {
            if(r >= right.size() || (l < left.size() && left[l] < right[r])) {
                arr[i] = left[l++];
            } else {
                arr[i] = right[r++];
            }
}
where len = n1 + n2
```

I personally find this way more readable and easier, but to each their own! (this is unstable and can be made stable, but I leave that part for the reader to figure out!)

edit: I noticed it's java, maybe `len--` won't work you can do `len >= 0` and `len--` inside the loop.